# iText7 - PdfFormField.setValue() fails if the /DA uses a decimal font size

Tags: itext, itext7

iText 7.0.0

i have a PDF created by Adobe LiveCycle ES 10 that's producing a TextField with a

```
/DA /Arial-BoldMT 9.00 Tf 0.000 0.000 1.000 rg
```

this causes a failure in PdfFormField.regenerateField() which expects the text font size to be an Integer (i don't see any specific mention in the PDF spec that this would be true)

an acceptable workaround for my particular case appears to be just setting /V in the dictionary, but curiously why does setValue() work so hard?

Comment: "but curiously why does setValue() work so hard"  <-- i see it now...appearance streams

Comment: I created a ticket in our closed ticketing system. The font size is of type PDF number. A PDF number can be an integer or a real. This means that a font size can be a decimal number. If iText 7 doesn't accept this, we should fix this.

Comment: thanks Bruno..i actually was just about to open a support ticket in Jira on this too.  For our particular case, we probably don't need font sizes to be universally treated as decimals (flooring down to an int would be acceptable...especially since almost every case i've run across is #.00)

Comment: But when we fix the problem, we should fix it for all decimal numbers. It's the same effort.

Comment: This indeed was a bug of iText which is fixed now and the fix will be available since 7.0.1 release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in iText 7.0.1. Font sizes are now handled as decimal values and exposed in the entire API as floats